# WinRT - Display popup at application startup not working in Release on real device

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, popup, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I am trying to display a popup when the application starts (the popup is designed to be an interstitial ad).

I'm using the "Popup" class and i'm setting its content / height / width before displaying it.

The application runs on Windows Phone 8.1 winRT.

I have tried several methods but each time :

- This works on emulator in Debug mode.
- This works on emulator in Release mode.
- This works on real device in Debug mode.

But this does not work on real device in Release mode (the popup is not displayed).

This is what i've tried :

**1:**

```
InterstitialPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

**2:**

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
dt.Tick += (o, o1) =>
{
    dt.Stop();
    InterstitialPopup.IsOpen = true;
};
dt.Start();
```

**3:**

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    InterstitialPopup.IsOpen = true;
});
```

**4:**

```
Task.Run(() => InterstitialPopup.IsOpen = true);
```

**5:**

```
Task t = new Task(() => InterstitialPopup.IsOpen = true );
t.RunSynchronously();
```

And combining those methods.

By placing breakpoints i can see that the code is called, but the popup is never displayed on a real device in Release mode.

By calling myself the popup by clicking on a button, the popup is displayed.

I have tried putting the code in various files (App.xaml.cs, in the ViewModel of my first page, in the xaml.cs of my first page, in a file that initializes some parameters of my app, .....).

Do you have an idea of why this works on emulator-release and device-debug but not on device-release ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering myself.

The issue was with the initialization of the popup (please note that i still don't know why this didn't work).

I had this kind of thing :

```
MyContent c = new MyContent();
c.Attribute1 = "something";
c.Attribute2 = "something";

Popup p = new Popup();
p.Child = c;
```

And i had to rewrite it like this to make it work on a real device in release mode :

```
Popup p = new Popup();
p.Child = new MyContent()
{
    Attribute1 = "something",
    Attribute2 = "something"
};
```

This way the popup is displayed when the app starts, running on a real device in release mode.